# Collect all objects from a Set of Sets with Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn Java Streams and trying to get a `HashSet<Person>` from a `HashSet<SortedSet<Person>>`.

```
HashSet<Person> students = getAllStudents();
HashSet<SortedSet<Person>> teachersForStudents = students.stream().map(Person::getTeachers).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
HashSet<Person> = //combine teachers and students in one HashSet
```

What I really want it to combine all teachers and all students in one `HashSet<Person>`. I guess I'm doing something wrong when I'm collecting my stream?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) each student into a stream formed by the student along with their teachers:

```
HashSet<Person> combined = 
    students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(student), student.getTeachers().stream()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

[`concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) is used to concatenate to the Stream of the teachers, a Stream formed by the student itself, obtained with [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-).

Comment: The first thing, I’d ask, is, whether it really has to be a `HashSet` or if any `Set` would do. Besides that, I’d reduce the workload of the nested operation. Since neither `HashSet` nor the unspecified result type of `toSet()` maintain an ordering, you can just concat’ the students as a whole rather than each student as a nested singleton stream: `Set<Person> combined = Stream.concat(students.stream(), students.stream().flatMap(student -> student.getTeachers().stream())) .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @Holger why not make that an answer?

Comment: as a reminder to myself, if one just wants a simple set of sets to one set, just a simple `Set combined = set.stream().flatMap(Collection:stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());` will do