# How to perform multiple operations on same custom object using Java 8

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I have a Role object which contains roleName, roleId and rolePermissions which is also a list of permissions object.

Now I want to retrieve roleName and add it to Set and from permissionList retrieve all permissions and add to the same Set to achieve this using pre Java 8 I have achieved using below code

```
   for (Role role : roleList) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
            List<Permission> permissions = role.getPermissions();
            for (Permission permission : permissions) {
                authorities
                        .add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + permission.getName()));
            }
        }
```

Using Java8 I have achieved the same using

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        roleList.stream().parallel().peek(role -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName())))
                .forEach(role -> role.getPermissions()
                        .forEach(p -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + p.getName()))));
```

I feel we are not leveraging full Java8 features and above is not correct way to achieve . How to achieve the same more effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) :

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities =
    roleList.stream()
            .flatMap(r->Stream.concat(Stream.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getRoleName())),
                                      r.getPermissions().stream().map(p->new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + p.getName()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: The signature is `<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`, so there is no problem to pass `Collectors.<GrantedAuthority>toSet()` (inferred from target type) to a `Stream<SimpleGrantedAuthority>`. Similarly, `Set<Object> s=Stream.of("hello", "world").collect(Collectors.<Object>toSet());` works without problems.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Holger  How to Handle Null check in above code for r.getPermissions()?

Comment: @rajadilipkolli: you mean `Role.getPermissions()` may return `null`? You should change that to return `Collections.emptyList()` instead. You should generally avoid methods returning `null` for a collection or array.

Answer (score 3):

Since the end goal is to obtain a general set which is not sorted, (and [as was pointed out to me on a very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466912/collect-all-objects-from-a-set-of-sets-with-java-stream/39467047#comment66255052_39467047)) you can also have:

```
Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream.concat(
  roleList.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName())),
  roleList.stream().flatMap(role -> role.getPermissions().stream()).map(p -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + p.getName()))
).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

which only concatenates a stream formed by the role names and the name of each permission in a role.

Comment: I am inclined towards this as this answer is clear and dont need much typecasting like the answer from @Eran

Comment: @rajadilipkolli: there is no type casting in Eran’s answer.

Comment: @Holger we are receiving Set<Object> from Eran's answer which we need to Typecast to Set<GrantedAuthority>

Comment: @rajadilipkolli: Eran’s answer contains an error, a relic of your original code, which you should have spotted yourself, if your tried to understand the solution instead of just doing copy&paste. If you remove the unnecessary `authorities.add` calls, the solution will do the same as Tunaki’s, as it’s exactly the same operation, only written as `concat` within `flatMap` instead of `flatMap` within `concat`.